# Get input of user from HTML form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a form that takes two text inputs: a first number and a second number. I'm trying to get the input given by the user and calculate the sum of it, but I'm unable to do so.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="">
  <label for="fnum">first Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum" placeholder="first num" /><br /><br />
  <label for="snum">second num:</label>
  <input type="number" id="snum" placeholder="second num" name="snum" /><br /><br />
  <!-- <label for="btn">Button</label> -->
  <button id="btn" onclick="ad(a,b)">add</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
a = document.querySelector("#fnum").value;

b = document.querySelector("#snum").value;
const ad = (a, b) => (c = a + b);
document.write(c);
```

Comment: unclear how a and b are updated.... It will only have the value when the page renders

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use document.write after the page has loaded. It will wipe the page
2. You need an event to trigger the summing and in the event handler you need to get the values, not outside it
3. I add the values into a span element so I can reset the form on submit

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // page load
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", e => { // better than the button click
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    const a = document.getElementById("fnum").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("snum").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `${a}+${b} = ${+a + +b}`; // cast to number - I use template literals to create a string
    e.target.reset(); // clear the form
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <label for="fnum">first Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum" placeholder="first num" /><br /><br />
  <label for="snum">second num:</label>
  <input type="number" id="snum" placeholder="second num" name="snum" /><br /><br />
  <button>add</button>
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? It is a working script using proper event handling

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` will change **the whole body**, rather use separate element which you edit on submit.

Also, since `.value` returns an string, we'll need to convert those values to integers to add them together, therefore `c = +a + +b`.

The `const ad = (a, b) => (c = a + b);` does not make that much sense, it's defining a function, `let c = +a + +b;` should be fine.

```js
function ad(event) {

  // Prevent form submit
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Get fields
  let a = document.querySelector("#fnum").value;
  let b = document.querySelector("#snum").value;
  
  // Sum
  let c = +a + +b;
  
  // Show
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = 'Sum: ' + c;
  
  // Reset form
  event.target.parentNode.reset()
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="fnum">first Number:</label>
  <input
    type="number"
    id="fnum"
    name="fnum"
    placeholder="first num"
  /><br /><br />
  <label for="snum">second num:</label>
  <input
    type="number"
    id="snum"
    placeholder="second num"
    name="snum"
  /><br /><br />
  <!-- <label for="btn">Button</label> -->
  <button id="btn" onclick="ad(event)">add</button>
</form>

<em id='sum'></em>
```

Comment: thanks this is working and understandable too. How can i clear the forms when i click sum

Comment: Please see my edit @sumitkhatrii. We know the button, it's passed by the event. `parentNode` is the `form`, using the `reset()` function will clear all the fields.

Comment: how can i remove the previous num sum and display new one. the older sum of the number are still showing up like this : Sum: 5Sum: 5

Comment: Instead off appending to the body, I've created an `<em>` element which we can update with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what the others have already posted it's customary now to add `addEventListener` to elements rather than use function calls inline. Here I've used a function called `handleClick` which is called when the button is clicked, and appends the values (coerced from their strings to numbers) of the cached input elements to a `div` on the page rather than using `document.write`.

If your script is in the `head` part of your HTML move it just before the `</body>` tag instead so that the DOM can load and the JavaScript can cache the loaded elements.

```js
// Cache the elements
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const a = document.querySelector('#fnum');
const b = document.querySelector('#snum');

// Add an event listener to the button that calls the function
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Prevent the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Display the result
  result.textContent = Number(a.value) + Number(b.value);
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fnum">first Number:</label>
  <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum" placeholder="first num" /><br /><br />
  <label for="snum">second num:</label>
  <input type="number" id="snum" placeholder="second num" name="snum" /><br /><br />
  <button id="btn">add</button>
</form>
<div id="result" />
```

Comment: Also your code needs to be executed AFTER the form has loaded, making it mandatory to place the code after the form. The snippet here at SO will wrap your code in a load event handler, masking this issue

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `write` call in the event handler. Furthermore, you should use a submit event if the button is being used within the form. Also, you will need to pares your integer values before adding them, because they will be treated as string concatenation.

I would also attach the handler to the form using JavaScript to have access to the event object. This allows you to prevent the default submission of the form from navigating away after you write the content to the page.

```js
const form = document.forms['calc'];

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const
    [ fnum, snum ] = form.elements,
    result = parseInt(fnum.value, 10) + parseInt(snum.value, 10);
  document.write(result);
};

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.25em;
}

label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7em 1fr;
}
```

```html
<form name="calc">
  <label for="fnum">
    First number:
    <input type="number" id="fnum" name="fnum" placeholder="First number..." />
  </label>
  <label for="snum">
    Second number:
    <input type="number" id="snum" name="snum" placeholder="Second number..."  />
  </label>
  <button id="btn">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should never use document.write after load. It wipes the page, scripts and all. 
Op wants to reuse the form, so the form needs to stay on the page.
Also no need to parseInt,10 from number fields. They do not handle octal or such.